# How do I get my keyboard to work in Grub on this old IBM ThinkCentre PC?

Tags: grub2

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on an old IBM ThinkCentre alongside Windows XP Professional. I have had problems with Ubuntu, so I would like to boot into Windows to delete the Ubuntu partition. Yet, my keyboard refuses to work during GRUB. I have used a BenQ and generic USB keyboard and have yet to try with a PS/2 keyboard.

I can use the BIOS, but it stops working during GRUB. The ThinkCentre has an old Celeron and 0.99GB of RAM.

Does anyone know how to make my keyboard work?

Comment: Ok sorry about that. I will try to edit it.

Comment: Also, I can only use the Terminal. No desktop environment loads for me in Ubuntu

Comment: Looks a lot better now! And guess what: I get your actual question now. :) Do you have any option in your BIOS for USB devices to change? E.g. "USB legacy devices" is a common one that saved me for these kind of tasks. Grub just uses the BIOS interfaces, so there's not much to try in that aspect. Also check if you can find a BIOS update. *Very important to note* is that removing the Ubuntu partition will break booting completely as Grub relies on it now! See also: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/88802)

Comment: I have seen the USB Legacy Devices fix before, but I don't think it will work as I can access the BIOS fine but not GRUB. But what do I know, I have no experience with Linux. Also I could find USB options but I was afraid I would mess something up (not that good at anything out of Windows, including the BIOS) And also, very unlikely for there to be a BIOS update as it is an old IBM. Thanks for the tip on removing Ubuntu, I would not be happy to be stuck with a computer that won't boot!